# My simple spring boot hibernate mapping problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, mapping

My TaskService

```
public TaskDTO save(TaskDTO taskEntity){
  Mapper<TaskDTO,TaskEntity> mapper = Mapping.from(taskEntity).to(TaskEntity.class).mapper();
  return taskRepository.save(taskEntity);
}
```

Hi everyone I am writing simple project and want TaskDTO convert TaskEntity and send TaskManager layer but
I don't know how to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeanUtils.copyProperties to convert DTO to entity, or entity to DTO.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
...
BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceObject, targetObject);
```

If you want to ignore some fields, just add them after the `targetObject`.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceObj, targetObj, "propertyToIgnoreA", "propertyToIgnoreB", "propertyToIgnoreC");
```